# keras model.fit_generator returning output of generator should be a tuple

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I'm new keras and  I can't figure out why is the model.fit_generator(...) returning the exception "Exception: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: None" where it shouldn't?
my data are 48*48 grayscale images of 7 classes.

my model.py file:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Convolution2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
import numpy

def get_model():
# implement your model here
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(48, 48, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(7))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

optimization_method = 'sgd'
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimization_method, metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
```

and my train.py :

```
import os
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from model import get_model


img_width, img_height = 48, 48

train_data_dir = 'resources/data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'resources/data/validation'
nb_train_samples = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(train_data_dir)])
nb_validation_samples = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(validation_data_dir)])
nb_epoch = 100

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, color_mode="grayscale",
target_size=(img_height, img_width), batch_size=128, class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir, color_mode="grayscale",
target_size=(img_height, img_width), batch_size=128, class_mode='categorical')

model = get_model()

for i in range(nb_epoch):
    print('epoch: ' + str(i))
    model.fit_generator(train_generator, samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples, nb_epoch=1,
    validation_data=validation_generator, nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)

    model.save_weights('resources/models/'+str(i))
```

and the traceback:

```
Using Theano backend.
Found 28709 images belonging to 7 classes.
Found 7178 images belonging to 7 classes.
epoch: 0
Epoch 1/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 28, in <module>
validation_data=validation_generator, nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 874, in fit_generator
pickle_safe=pickle_safe)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1417, in fit_generator
'or (x, y). Found: ' + str(generator_output))
Exception: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: None
```